# Return nil when break the injection block earilier

Tags: ruby

I want to sum up the orders amount.

but if `order.upgrade != nil` I will end the block instantly.

But I got the `nil` value.

That wasn't my expectation.

How to achieve my goal?

Thanks

```
points = orders.inject(0) do |sum, order |
  break if order.upgrade != nil      
  sum += order.actual_amount if order.actual_amount
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
points = orders.inject(0) do |sum, order |
  break sum unless order.upgrade.nil?      
  sum += order.actual_amount || 0
end
```

Comment: From the [break statement docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement): *break accepts a value that supplies the result of the expression it is "breaking" out of*